# CreateProcess not working

Tags: c++, process, createprocess

I am having problems with getting the following code to work in C++ (VC++ console app). It simply doesn't create the process, but it prints out the error text.

```
static void main(){
    char *hotkeyexe = "cmd";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;

    if(!CreateProcess(hotkeyexe, "", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
        printf("error");
        scanf("%d");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int main`, not `static void main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to zero out STARTUPINFO.

```
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
```

Comment: got it figured out. i had to inverse the first 2 params (no idea why), but it works now. thanks. will mark your answer as the right one, because without your suggestion, the program wouldn't have worked either.

Comment: Compile with all warnings on. "Suspicious pointer conversion" is usually a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 1):

I quote from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The function will not use the search path. This parameter must include the file name extension; no default extension is assumed.

So you cannot just use cmd. It will depend on your working dir if it will work. If you use a full path it will work. E.g this is a working example on my machine.

```
char *hotkeyexe = "c:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));

if(!CreateProcess(hotkeyexe, "", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    printf("error");
scanf("%d");
```